# SQLite3 in c++ outputing empty list on SELECT

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I am currently working on c++ with SQLite3, everything works fine, i can add stuff in the table, but when i do a `SELECT * FROM myTable;` is returns me `(null)`...
the variable `rc` of

```
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg;
int rc;
std::string sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
char csql[sql.size()+1];
strcpy(csql, csql.c_str()); // String to char*
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, csql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg); // rc = 21 Error
...
```

is 21.. According to https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html it means that I "Used the library incorrectly".. I then checked with python and online sql on the same `.db` file and it outputs me what is good..

If anyone could help me and explain me what I did wrong and how to correct it?
Thank you very much !

ps:
here is my function addUser in case the problem is in the add..

```
bool addUser(std::string username, std::string password){
    char cpassword[password.size()+1];
    strcpy(cpassword, password.c_str());
    std::string shashedP = hashPass(cpassword); // hashPass returns std::string

    std::string sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, passw) VALUES ('" + username  + "', " + shashedP + ");";
    char csql[sql.size()+1];
    strcpy(csql, sql.c_str());
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, csql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg); // rc = SQLITE3_OK = 0 everytime
    ...
```

Comment: Fyi, I honestly see no need for the `csql` VLA in this code  (or any of the VLAs, but that one is handy as an example). For one, VLAs aren't standard, so you should avoid using them. Second, there is zero reason not to just pass `sql.c_str()` as the second argument to `sqlite3_exec`, relieving you of using the questionable VLA in the first place. Finally, a warning: stringing together SQL in the fashion you are is a recipe for [sql injection exploits](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's... strange... code (Plus as was already mentioned, not really valid C++, though some compilers do support C style VLAs as an extension). The normal workflow is to use a prepared statement for anything returning rows, or taking user-supplied arguments in the form of placeholders. `sqlite3_exec()` is mostly only good for creating tables and such where there's no results and no runtime defined arguments to pass to the query.

For example:

```
std::string query = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE name = ?";
std::string name = "Bob";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), query.size(), &stmt, nullptr) != SQLITE_OK) {
  // Error reporting and handling
}
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, name.c_str(), name.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
  int foo = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
  // Do stuff with the current row's foo
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

[More reading](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).